# Move Folder from Sharepoint site to another

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am using Move-PnPFolder to move folders within a SharePoint site, but this will not move folder from one site to another! Is there any way to do that, as it is an option in the web UI?

Answer (score 0):

as per Microsoft answer on [github](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2748) the MovePnPFolder is currently lacking this feature. Instead they proposed another command `Move-PnPFile` to move folder/file from one site to another. While the command looks like limited to files, it is not, and it can move folders as well

```
Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl /sites/source/shared%20documents/Test -TargetServerRelativeLibrary /sites/target/shared%20documents -Force -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists -IgnoreVersionHistory -AllowSmallerVersionLimitOnDestination -AllowSchemaMismatch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look following methods, they can move file/folder to another site:

- [CSOM-MoveCopyUtil.MoveFolder method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/mt844929(v=office.15))

Demo: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-move-files-using-powershell.html

- [CreateCopyJobs API](https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/createcopyjobs-api-copy-move-SharePoint-files-folders)

Demo script: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/13b6abdb-d0b7-499d-a418-af23f72e0d81/want-to-move-files-from-one-documet-library-to-another-document-library-between-2-site-collection-in?forum=sharepointdevelopment